# How to make cascade dropdown list in Datasheet View/Quick Edit mode?

Tags: dropdown, datasheet, quick-edit

I have a list with a need for cascade dropdown list. I've followed the instruction [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using) and successfully create a cascade dropdown in a **form**.

However, I'd like to ask for the possibility of creating a cascade dropdown within the Datasheet view or Quick edit mode.

Appreciation in advance.